# Delphi AdoConnection Reconnect

Tags: delphi, ado

I have just decided to solve the "Connection" problem when a MSSQL Database server is restarted, and the connection is dropped eternally.

The only solution so far has been to restart the program, not always so easy on server far-far away (and the problem must first be detected).

**The code below seems to be working fine, but can a skilled ADO person look deeper into the code and see any errors/problems or improvements needed with this code? **

```
Type
  TComponentHelper = class helper for TComponent
     Procedure Reconnect(var AdoConn:TAdoConnection; ConnStr:String);
  end;

procedure TComponentHelper.Reconnect(var AdoConn: TAdoConnection; ConnStr: String);
begin
  if Assigned(AdoConn) then begin
    FreeAndNil(AdoConn);
    AdoConn := TAdoConnection.Create(Self);
    AdoConn.ConnectionString := ConnStr;
    AdoConn.LoginPrompt := false;
    SetConnAdoComponent(Self,AdoConn);
    AdoConn.Open;
  end;
end;

procedure SetConnAdoComponent(aSrc:TComponent; var AdoConn:TAdoConnection);
var
  Ctrl : TComponent;
  i    : Integer;
begin
  if (aSrc = Nil) then Exit;
  if (aSrc.ComponentCount &lt;= 0) then Exit;
  for i:=0 to aSrc.ComponentCount-1 do begin
    Ctrl := aSrc.Components[i];
    if (Ctrl is TAdoQuery) then TAdoQuery(Ctrl).Connection := AdoConn;
    if (Ctrl is TAdoTable) then TAdoTable(Ctrl).Connection := AdoConn;
    if (Ctrl is TAdoDataset) then TAdoDataset(Ctrl).Connection := AdoConn;
  end;
end
```

I Call Reconnect() from the Exception part in a TForm or TDataModule, AdoConn is the name of the TAdoConnection component and the ConnStr is the complete connectionstring used.

```
Except
  On E:EOleException do begin
    ReConnect(AdoConn,ConnStr);
  end;
  On E:Exception do begin
    ReConnect(AdoConn,ConnStr);
  end;
End;
```

Comment: I think handling of all exceptions by reconnecting is a bit too broad. You could end up with very strange behaviour when you try to reconnect to the database while for instance in a query error or memory errors. The second thing is that you are destroying the adoconnection object while other components still have it in use, it could even be in use in one of the callees of the procedure where you handle your exception. I think you are on the wrong path here. Try and create your own TAdoConnection that handles this error and can reconnect.

Comment: If the code works, surely this belongs over at the CodeReview stackexchange site? Also, have you simply tried `Close` and `Open` the connection?

Comment: @kobik:  As usual you were quite right about my answer, which I've deleted.  Thanks.  I may have another go later.

Comment: Are you sure about the "Connection" problem dropped eternally you describe? I didn't test it when the SQL Server is restarted, but isn't a `AdoConn.Close` and then `AdoConn.Open` solves the problem?

Comment: Craig - Close and Open does not work. It has to do with OleDB keeping the Connection in the Connection pool (still in error). So Destroy - Create is one way. Did not know about CodeReview Stackexchange.

Comment: @CraigYoung, The fact that this code "works" does not mean it's the correct approach for the problem OP is facing. In my view it answers "what have you tried?" :)

Comment: @kobik Question says: "code below seems to be working fine, but can a skilled ADO person look deeper into the code and see any errors/problems or improvements needed" - this is the _raison d'etre_ for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). You also say: "does not mean it's the correct approach for the problem" - again the _very point of CodeReview_. You're welcome to go over to [CR meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/) and argue for the domain to be put to rest. I won't stop you, but please don't argue that "_the Q is on topic for CR_", and so doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of destroying the `TADOConnection` your best option is to replace the internal `TADOConnection.ConnectionObject` with a new one. e.g.

```
uses ActiveX, ComObj, ADOInt;

function CreateADOConnectionObject: _Connection;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_Connection, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, Result));
end;

var
  NewConnectionObject: _Connection;
  ConnectionString: WideString;
begin
  ConnectionString := ADOConnection1.ConnectionString;
  NewConnectionObject := CreateADOConnectionObject;
  NewConnectionObject.ConnectionString := ConnectionString;
  ADOConnection1.Close;
  // set the new connection object
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionObject := NewConnectionObject;
  ADOConnection1.Open;
end;
```

Setting `ADOConnection1.ConnectionObject := NewConnectionObject` will destroy the previous internal `FConnectionObject` and set a new connection object to be used by the  `TADOConnection` object.

Also you need to handle the *specific* `EOleException.ErrorCode` (probably `E_FAIL`) at the time of the exception so that you sure you don't handle other exceptions which has nothing to do with your issue.

I did not try this with your specific scenario (SQL restart). I leave it up to you for testing.

**EDIT:** Tested with SQL Server 2014 and `SQLOLEDB.1`. My application connected to the SQL, and after restarting the SQL, I could not reproduce the described behavior *"connection is dropped eternally"*. a `Close`/`Open` did the job, and the client re-connected.

Comment: On your edit, I got the same; even killing the sqlserver process. OP must be doing something significantly different to us for `Close` / `Open` to not work.